# Как сделать изображение нормальным

Tags: java, android, bitmap, photo, android-camera

Фото получается растянутым, как сделать его нормальным?

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera)
{
    imagesFolder.mkdir(); 
    MyappDir.mkdir();

    if (imagesFolder.listFiles().length == 0 | schet == null)
    {
            DataOutputStream out = null;
            Integer n = Integer.valueOf(1);
            try
            {
                out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(schet));
                out.writeInt(n.intValue());
                out.close();
                File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_" + n + ".jpg");
                Bitmap imageBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(paramArrayOfByte, 0, paramArrayOfByte.length);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
                int width = display.getWidth();
                int height = display.getHeight();
                imageBmp = imageBmp.createBitmap(imageBmp, 0, 0, imageBmp.getWidth(), imageBmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                imageBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBmp, width, height, false);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(image); 
                imageBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, fos);
                fos.close();

                galleryAddPic();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

изображение растягивается потому, что соотношение сторон экрана не соответствует соотношению сторон камеры. `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` создает как раз растянутое\сжатое изображение

Чтобы получить обрезанное изображение ,а не растянутое, можете использовать

`imageBmp = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(imageBmp, width, height);`
Вместо
`imageBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBmp, width, height, false);`